# How to connect to a remote MySQL database with Java (jdbc)?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I tried to connect my Database on my virtual Server (Debian10) with a Java program on my computer (Windows 10).
I tried this:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://xyz.de:3306/xyz? useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezon 
    e=Europe/Berlin";
    String user = "xyz";
    String password = "xyz";
    try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, 
    password)) {
    System.out.println("Successfully connected to database.");
        
    }catch(SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

And the error ist:

```
   Communications link failure
   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not 
   received any packets from the server.
```

I created the user with "phpMyAdmin" and I gave it all permissions.
And in the hostname field, I entered a "%";)
I also activated the port on the server.

Thanks for Help :)

Comment: mysql databases aren't usually accessible directly from the internet for security reasons. so see if your provider doesn't support ssh  and use the tunnel

Comment: You might want to check the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Comment: that is ot allowed here. but there are plenty of examples https://www.it-swarm.com.de/de/java/ssh-verbindung-mit-java/969823644/

Comment: @nbk First of all thanks for answering :)
Now I've tried this https://www.journaldev.com/235/java-mysql-ssh-jsch-jdbc and I'm still getting the same error.
But just the ssh connection as in your example worked :)